# MKMapView Broken on OS X 10.11?

Tags: macos, cocoa, mkmapview, osx-elcapitan

I have a production App that uses MKMapView and which shows users a Map. They can zoom using +/- key or via mouse scroll wheel and drag map to a location.

On OS X 10.11.x the drag to location seems to no longer work. All zooming functions work, but not map dragging. This is true of both the production version (currently in the Mac App Store) as well as development versions built using Xcode 7.0.1.

The OS X Deployment target is 10.9.

The MKMapView is added to views manually using this code:

```
_mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
_mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_mapView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
_mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
_mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
_mapView.pitchEnabled = NO;
_mapView.rotateEnabled = NO;
_mapView.showsZoomControls = YES;
_mapView.scrollEnabled = YES;
_mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
_mapView.showsBuildings = YES;
_mapView.delegate = self;
[self addSubview:_mapView];
```

Has anyone else seen this or have any ideas as to what might be going on, or if I am missing something? I'm hoping this is NOT an OS X MKMapView bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**** **Update: This issue is resolved in OSX 10.11.2. Yay Apple!** ****

This ***is*** a confirmed bug (OSX 10.11.0 and 10.11.1). Radar: 22903136.